# DataAnnotations Automatic Handling of int is Causing a Roadblock

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, attributes, data-annotations

Summary: DataAnnotation's automatic handling of an "int?" is making me rethink using them at all.

Maybe I'm missing something and an easy fix but I can't get DataAnnotations to cooperate. I have a public property with my own custom validation attribute:

```
[MustBeNumeric(ErrorMessage = "Must be a number")]
public int? Weight { get; set; }
```

The point of the custom validation attribute is do a quick check to see if the input is numeric and display an appropriate error message. The problem is that when DataAnnotations tries to bind a string to the int? is automatically doesn't validate and displays a "The value 'asdf' is not valid for Weight."

For the life of me I can't get DataAnnotations to stop handling that so I can take care of it in my custom attribute.

This seems like it would be a popular scenario (to validate that the input in numeric) and I'm guessing there's an easy solution but I didn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, even simple things like this might become a real PITA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a workaround (as I wouldn't really call this a solution). Add a `Messages.resx` file inside the `App_GlobalResources` folder of your web application. Add the following resource inside:

```
Key: PropertyValueInvalid
Value: {0} Must be a number
```

In the `Application_Start` method of `Global.asax` add the following:

```
DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "Messages";
```

Comment: Yikes. Not exactly seamless. I'm tempted to change those properties on my view models that are ints to strings. Then I can run them through the DataAnnotations validations as well a few custom attributes and if they're good to go convert them to an int when I map from view model to entity. In your opinion, does that sound like a decent solution?